# Rundeck Status shows "dead" despite rundeck being up and running

Tags: rundeck

The rundeck instance is up and running but when I execute the following command it shows:

```
 $/etc/init.d/rundeckd status
    Status rundeckd: rundeckd is running (pid=37296, port=4440)   dead
```

Kindly help me out here on how to get this glitch fixed/?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can run /etc/init.d/rundeckd stop and it should clear out the old pid file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the issue is this particular glitch is coming with a fresh installation ... the commands /etc/init.d/rundeckd stop and /etc/init.d/rundeckd start works fine but when I fire this command /etc/init.d/rundeckd status then it shows the proper pid and port but the "dead" status comes too along with it.... is this a bug ? I am using rundeck 2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

You can check for java version (exact with subversion) in /app/rundeck/etc/Profile and java installed on the particular server where rundeck is installed. Both should be identical, if not update the java version from the server to the file/app/rundeck/etc/Profile. Then restart rundeck, this should fix the issue .